# How can I detect mobile keys from a web application?

Tags: html, jsp, mobile, browser

Summary of desired behavior: we have a html video (that can be hosted anywhere such as youtube, vimeo, etc) inside of a .JSP webpage. When user plays the video, it changes to fullscreen-mode and starts the presentation. If user taps on [return key] of the device, we need to show an alert window. This behavior must work with WindowsPhone, BlackBerry, IPhone and Android devices, but for now, we're taking efforts only on WindowsPhone to diminish the problem's scope.

How can I implement such behavior? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok pal, what did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Diodeus, thanks for replying.
We're still trying to see if this is architecturally possible. I've suggested an approach where the device try to detect when the page is reloaded, but I'm not sure if this fits as the video is played out of the browser by default device video player.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry for this Timothy! I've mistaken it.